# Which JMX attributes do measure the number of requests and their processing time?

Tags: tomcat, jvm, monitoring, jmx

I am trying to improve the performance monitoring of several Tomcat instances (Jira and Cinfluence) and I have trouble finding the right beans/attributes/properties to monitor.

I already got information regarding CPU load, threads and memory but I need those related to the number of requests served and the (average) time needed to respond.

This would help me find out if the performance problems are appearing under increased normal load or are cause by special kind of requests that are slowing down the entire server.

Comment: Any progress on this?  Have you investigated the mbeans available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment we are using DataDog and New Relic to monitor several JVMs and at least the second one is providing very good insights regarding number of requests, they duration and results.